# Trying to add data from an ifstream to a ofstream. output looks correct but when I try to add the same data to the output file, it doesn't transfer

Tags: c++

I am working on a project where I must open a file, run the data, identify certain aspects and select those lines. When I run the program, the answers come out correct. Then I have to add the data points to an ofstream file, which I have labelled. When I try to add the data to the file, it doesn't move any data over. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my current program.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string fileName;
    ifstream iFile;
    iFile.open(fileName);
    // keep asking the user for file name again and again till the file opens successfully
    while(1){
    cout<<"Open File: ";
    cin>>fileName;
    iFile.open(fileName);//open file
        if(!iFile){
            cout << "Could not open " << fileName << endl;
        }else//valid file name,exit the loop
            break;
        }
    string plate;
    string date;
    string time;
    string weight;
    string speed;
    int foundWeight = 0;
    int foundSpeed = 0;
    int count = 0;
    vector<string> v1;
    vector<string> v2;
    ofstream outFile("[10-09-2022] Report.txt:", ios::app);

    while (getline(iFile, plate, ',')) {
    getline(iFile, date, ',') ;
    getline(iFile, time, ',') ;
    getline(iFile, weight, ',');
    foundWeight = stoi(weight);
    getline(iFile, speed);
    foundSpeed = stoi(speed);
        if(foundWeight < 5000 && foundSpeed > 45){
            cout << "[" << time << "]" << ' ' << plate << endl;
            outFile << "[" << time << "]" << ' ' << plate << endl;
            count++;
        }else if(foundWeight >= 5000 && foundSpeed > 30){
            cout << "[" << time << "]" << ' ' << plate << endl;
            outFile << "[" << time << "]" << ' ' << plate << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << count << " violations logged.\n";
    outFile << count;
    outFile.close();

    return 0;   
}
,,,

//output is:
Open File: a5_short.dat
[06:11] MVE-717
[06:23] OLC-651
[06:28] KQJ-359
[06:37] NFT-062
[06:41] MCW-399
[06:45] BWQ-255
[06:49] ZKL-544
[07:00] FHQ-348
[07:11] QME-845
[07:13] OWG-325
[07:34] NNJ-571
[07:43] ZKI-228
12 violations logged.

The values shown are correct, but won't transfer to the "[10-09-2022] Report.txt:" file.
```

Comment: You are not doing any error checking. You do not even know if the file was opened successfully. You have specified openmode `ios::app`, and it's unclear why. Does the file already exist and you wish to add more to the end of it? When specifying an open mode you usually need to specify `ios::out` as well: `ios::app | ios::out`

Comment: `string fileName; ifstream iFile; iFile.open(fileName);`You probably don't want to open the file with an empty string for a filename, especially since you try and open it again after the input of the filename. I would guess the output file never opens. If you're on Windows then a colon isn't a valid character for a filename.